# Is there an Application panel in Firefox DevTools like in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: browser, firefox-developer-tools

The developer tools in Google Chrome have an *Application* panel.

[image: Application panel in Chrome]

This tool contains the page's manifest etc. But I can't find this tool in Firefox. Is there such a panel in the Firefox DevTools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the manifest part, no, there isn't, because Firefox doesn't implement [Web Manifest](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=997779) yet.

But the Firefox DevTools support the other parts of Chrome's *Application* panel, they are just placed somewhere else.

The storages (cache, cookies, Indexed DB, Local Storage, and Session Storage) can be inspected in the [*Storage* panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector).

Service Workers can be inspected on `about:serviceworkers`.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking for answer in September 2019:

Firefox is working on an Application Panel, similar to one in Chrome. The progress can be tracked at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=DevTools&component=Application%20Panel).

[image: Firefox devtools Application panel showing Manifest details]
*Firefox devtools Application panel showing Manifest details*

It is disabled by default (as of September 11, 2019) and can be enabled via `devtools.application.enabled` flag on `about:config` page.